# Passing MongoDB resultset data from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets, mongodb-query

I have the servlet below which takes a parameter "name" from jsp and performs search in MongoDB to get the records based on that name.

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
 String name= request.getParameter("name");

// Create Mongo connection to the DB
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost", 27017);

// Select the DB
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("myDatabase");

// Select the collection
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");


 Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document.toJson());
    }
};
 collection.find(eq("name", name)).forEach(printBlock);
 }
```

I want only those records which match with "name". I get till here successfully. So next how do I pass them to jsp from servlet and how are they received at JSP?.

The following is my simple JSP Page which just takes the "name" from user. I need to print the result passed from servlet to this JSP in a table form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @sinclair I would like to know how I need to pass this "document.toJson()" which prints my results to JSP.  Like what would be the statement to do it and then how would I retrieve it in JSP?

Comment: If you take a look at point 2 of the top answer of the linked question this should give you an idea of how to do it. Create a list of the objects you retrieve from the db and attach it to the request. Then use a `<c:forEach` to create your table.

Comment: @sinclair Yes but before that since I am new to Mongodb, I wish to know how to convert the results from
collection.find(eq("name", name)).forEach(printBlock);
to String or how do I store them and in wht format?

Comment: forget about the 'forEach`, take a look at the mongodb documentary and you will find out that Json is your friend...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to implement the MVC2 pattern "from scratch" (i.e. you dont use a MVC framework like Struts or Spring MVC). There are 3 things that you need to do:

1. attach the object to the request with `request.setAttribute(collection)`
2. transfer control to the JSP (with the `requestDispatcher`
3. within the JSP, use the expression language to retrieve the collection

Comment: I actually need help with what to pass from the above code. 
 And how to pass that code and how to recieve in JSP. I am new to JSP and MongoDB here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is where I get my resulting answer.
collection.find(eq("name", name)).forEach(printBlock);
So how do I pass it like?

Comment: Well, there are different questions. First, you need a Java object (from collection.find()). When you have that, you use req.setAttribute() to pass it to the JSP.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I am struggling with it, could you show it how it will be using my code above?

Comment: collection.find(eq("name", name)).forEach(printBlock); statement returns null so I cannot assign it to anything to pass it to JSP

Comment: in the forEach, pass a method where you build a data structure (a list).

Comment: I am not able to. I would like the help with doing it using my code. Could you help with it?